# PDF doesn't download with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, pdf, web-scraping, puppeteer

So I'm trying to download a pdf file that opens in a pop up, like this.

[image]

Using this code right here to get the pop up and download it to './'.

```
const popUp = await popUpPromise
        await popUp.waitFor(5000)
        // await popUp.waitForSelector('.content')
        const pdf = await popUp.$$eval('html', e => e)
        await console.log(pdf)
        await popUp._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './'})
```

But not only it isn't downloading as I expected, but the html from the pop up is returning empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to download a pdf from a popup you will need to simulate pressing ctrl-s once the popup loads. It should download to your specified folder in your downloadbehavior settings. Try using `await page.type()` or `await page.press()`